# Django: fullcalendar weeknumber

Tags: django, fullcalendar, week-number

I try to display week numbers but nothing happens

I put weeknumber in the javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                    weekNumbers: true,
                    height:400,
        header: {

            left: 'prev,next today, save',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,agendaFourDay'
        },

                   'defaultView': 'month',
        editable: true,
       .....
```

what is this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import necessary CSS and js for it ?

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
```

moreover

> weekNumbers:
>
> If set to true, week numbers will be displayed in a separate left column in the month/basic views as well as at the top-left corner of the agenda views. See [Available views](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/)

Comment: I imported : jquery-1.7.1.min.js, fullcalendar.min.js, moment.min.js, fullcalendar.css, jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js

Comment: You can press F12 and check in networks tab if required files are loading?